# Use variables (or store) in all page/component, in nuxt3

Tags: nuxtjs3, pinia

I am using nuxt3, pinia.
I can use the user, is_login variables in a specific vue page, as seen below.

```
import { useAuthStore } from "~/stores/myCustomAuthStore";
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'
const authStore = useAuthStore();
const {user, is_login} = storeToRefs(authStore)
```

What I want is to use the user, is_login variables in another page (or component) without writing the 4 lines of code above.

I think I need to use a plugin or module or nuxtApp.provide, how should I do it detaily?

------ what i tried is -------

I made plugins/common.ts

```
import { useAuthStore } from "~/stores/myCustomAuthStore";
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    const authStore = useAuthStore();
    const {user, is_login} = storeToRefs(authStore)
    nuxtApp.provide('user', user.value)
    nuxtApp.provide('is_login', is_login.value)
}
```

and I put below code every

```
const is_login = useNuxtApp().$is_login
const user = useNuxtApp().$user
```

This is not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a composable for this (see https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/composables#composables-directory):

Create a `composables/use-auth.ts` file in the "composables" directory

```js
// composables/use-auth.ts

import { useAuthStore } from '~/stores/myCustomAuthStore';
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia';

export const useAuth = () => {
  const pinia = usePinia();
  const authStore = useAuthStore(pinia);

  const { user, is_login } = storeToRefs(authStore);

  return {
    user,
    is_login,
  };
}
```

Then in your component you can use it like:

```html
<script setup>
const { user, is_login } = useAuth();
</script>
```

Comment: Good. But in this case, making a plugin is not suitable?